# Background image displaying poorly on iOS

Tags: css

So I added background image to an element for mobile devices in css, a regular png image to a div, positioned them absolute and thats it. However on iPhones and iPads it displays horribly, the image is darker, doesnt stay where it should on scroll (it moves, disappears, reappears...).

Screenshot from iPhone:

[image]

Screenshot from Android:

[image]

You can see that on first image it is very very different for some reason.

CSS:

```
padding: 0 !important;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
width: 25px;
height: 37px;
background: url('../../Content/emerge-tiles/Images/left-opacity.png');
```

Comment: Using pixels will result in a mismatch on Android and iPhone, consider using % or em.

Comment: Your screen shot not displaying

Comment: @MaheswaranS Not sure about that, I can see them..?